# Limiting number of checkbox to be check jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, limit

I have a web page with several groups of checkboxes (within each group, all checkboxes share the same class).
I want not only to limit the number of checkboxes that could be checked, but also the following - if the maximum number of checkboxes to be checked is 3, and the user checked a 4th checkbox, instead of showing a message, I would like to deselect the checkbox that was selected the longest time ago. How is this achieved considering I have multiple groups of checkboxes and each group has a different maximum allowed checkboxes number?

Btw, I am not using the jQuery UI checkbox element.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code you have so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: I'm just not really sure how to go about it. I could technically catch the change event for a specific group only, and then look at the status of all the checkboxes on that group and work it out - but how do create an event for a specific group only, and how do check which checkboxes in a specific group are checked?

Comment: You can use jQuery's delegate() method for intercepting just some checkboxes clicks, if they are under the same parent element (like a `<div>` for example)

Comment: they are under a specific div - how do I do that?

Comment: gonna answer that question at least, keep asking in the comments there if you want to and I'll edit

Comment: Can you at least show your html mark-up?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to:

1. attach events to these checkboxes
2. store information about when they were checked
3. in case the checked checkbox is the fourth one, find the first one checkbox checked and uncheck it

You can use the following features of jQuery:

- `.delegate()`, `.change()`, `.live()` or `.bind()` to attach events,
- `data-` HTML attributes to store JS timestamps (eg. you can have `<input type="checkbox" data-checked="1310950561097" />`),
- `.parents()` to select the container of the checkboxes' group,
- jQuery's `.each()` function to walk through all the checked checkboxes within same group (same container mentioned above),

By employing these features you should achieve what you need.

Comment: thanks for your input. my actual checkboxes are inside td's, inside tr's, inside a table, inside a div. i can either have the div or the table have a unique id for each group, but this: $('#div-id').delegate('checkbox', 'change', function (event) {
        alert("change to checkboxs");
    });    doesn't trigger anything. why is this?

Comment: @Raiders: because what you have just quoted searches for `<checkbox>` tags instead of `<input type="checkbox" />` tags. Try to replace `'checkbox'` with `'input[type="checkbox"]'` and it should work. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZzZE/) as a proof.

Comment: @Raiders: Btw. If this does not make difference to you, you may wish to give the same class for each group of checkboxes (assign class eg. `checkGroup` for container containing checkboxes from a single group) - it will be easier to distinguish what is a group and what is not (you would not need to check for multiple IDs that distinguish groups). Then you would be able to count only checked checkboxes from the same container with `checkGroup` class, that the currently checked checkbox is located in.

Answer (score 0):

to append an event to a group of checkboxes you use jQuery's `delegate` method like this:

```
$('#checkbox-container').delegate('checkbox', 'change', function (event) {
  // event.target is the clicked checkbox element here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts for this problem are:

```
var checkorder = [];
$('input:checkbox.checkboxes').click(
    function(){
        checkorder.push($(this).index('input:checkbox'));
        if (checkorder.length > 3){
            $('input:checkbox.checkboxes').eq(checkorder[0]).removeProp('checked');
            checkorder.splice(0,1);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CeT63/1/).

Problems with this approach:

1. It applies the selection to all checkboxes with the same `class`.
2. Doesn't differentiate between a click to check, or uncheck, a checkbox.

---

References:

- [`:checkbox`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/).
- [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/).
- [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: i like your solution. i just added the following the handle a situation of unchecking of a checked box:        var loc = $.inArray(checked, temp);
       if (-1 == loc) {
        temp.push(checked);
       } else {
        temp.splice(loc, 1);
       }   does this make sense to you?

Comment: It seems to, yeah; ...bearing in mind it's twenty to four in the morning where I am, and I can't sleep. So...my judgement isn't, probably, at its best. JS Fiddle it, maybe?